# Android GIS app to find specific device

Tags: android, maps, gis

Are there any apps that will track a specific device in a map view? Maybe track by phone number, or pair it using the same app. If possible without "Hack"ish method.

I want to use this app so I can track our office shuttle bus location.

Comment: No specific app in mind for that use-case – but be welcome to check with my list of [Location Sharing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_sharefake#group_565) apps. If you find something suitable there: You can always [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and gain reputation that way :)